# DHTMLX Scheduler.Can i get text from LightBox Checkbox to the EventBox?

Tags: dhtmlx-scheduler

Can i get text from LightBox Checkbox to the EventBox?
For Example, this example [link](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/samples/02_customization/13_single_checkbox_section.html)  have 1 checkbox in LightBox with text. I want that when i clicked checkbox and save - eventbox show text from this checkbox.

This is possible? Thank you!

Comment: Please provide the correct urls.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should set scheduler.locale.labels.section_checkme value as event.text. Please see [example](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/snippet/0e0f7444) how to implement it.